# How to load xml elements containing attributes in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008

I'm using SQL Server 2008 and I'm having trouble getting all data out of this xml:

```
DECLARE @xml xml

SELECT @xml =
'<dlines id="1234">
  <dline time="16h49" order="1">bladibla</dline> 
  <dline time="16h50" order="2">more bladibla</dline> 
</dlines>'
```

I can get the values of the attributes of the dline element using:

```
SELECT  TimeStr = dLine.value('@time', 'nvarchar(20)'),
OrderNo = dLine.value('@order', 'int'),
StatusStr = dLine.value('@status', 'nvarchar(20)'),
PeriodStr = dLine.value('@period', 'nvarchar(20)')
FROM    @afpxml.nodes('/dlines/dline') as XTbl(dLine)
```

But how do I get the value of dline element itself (the 'bladibla1')?

Thnx a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just query the value of `.`, the current node:

```
DlineItself = dLine.value('.', 'nvarchar(20)')
```